# How to implement touch controls on my code?

Tags: javascript

How I put in my funtion moveBloco() to control the white bars through the touch.

I want to make the white bars touchable for a smarthphone user. To move the bars up and down through the touch.

```
    function moveBloco(){
        if(87 in keyBoard && left.y > 0)
            left.y -= left.speed;
        if(83 in keyBoard && left.y + left.altura < canvas.height)
            left.y += left.speed;
        if(38 in keyBoard && right.y >0)
            right.y -= right.speed;
        if(40 in keyBoard && right.y + right.altura < canvas.height)
            right.y += right.speed;
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bd7v016e/1/

Comment: I tried you app on jsfiddle.
It seems that all is alright
I set the speed at 5, it is better for me.
I don't see any problem.
Can you detail your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle touch using [TouchEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Touch_events). You'll have to add 3 more event listeners corresponding to `touchstart`, `touchmove`, and `touchend`. For a touch you can get the pageX and pageY. You'll have to convert these to position relative to the canvas and apply your logic for moving the bars up or down.

```js
document.addEventListener("touchstart", handleTouchStart, false);
document.addEventListener("touchend", handleTouchMove, false);
document.addEventListener("touchend", handleTouchEnd, false);

var touchPosition = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};

function handleTouchStart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    touchPosition.x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
    touchPosition.y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
    var canvasPosition = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (touchPosition.x - canvasPosition.left > canvas.width/2) {
        // Trigger Right Bar
        if (touchPosition.y - canvasPosition.top > right.y) {
            // Move Down the Right Bar
        }
        else {
            // Move Up the Right Bar
        }
    }
    else {
        // Trigger Left Bar and apply same logic as above
        if (touchPosition.y - canvasPosition.top > right.y) {
            // Move Down the left bar
        }
        else {
            // Move Up the left bar
        }
    }
}

function handleTouchMove(e) {
    // Handle When User drags along the touch point
}

function handleTouchEnd(e) {
    // Handle Touch End
}
```